# error: ld returned 1 exit status C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Escrevi esse código em C++ no Codeblocks com a classe Registrar_moradores, mas esta dando o erro

> error: ld returned 1 exit status

que não encontrei nada que me ajudasse na internet. Não sei programar muito bem ainda.

Em um exemplo, meu professor usou esse modo para "chamar a classe" (não sei como se diz, declarar talvez?):

```
int main()
{
  Automovel p;
  p.CadastrarAutomovel();
  p.ImprimirAutomovel();
  system("pause");
}
```

e eu não entendi o porque do nome da classe e depois o "p" e em seguida chamar as funções com "p." no começo. Já vi outros exemplos mas as letras eram diferentes.

meu código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Registrar_moradores
{
private:

    char nome[200][50];
    int telefone[200], npessoas[200],op,linha;

public:
  void cadastro() {

    do{
      cout<<"***CADASTRAMENTOS DOS MORADORES***"<<endl;
      cout <<"\nNome:";
      cin >>nome[linha];
      cout <<"\nNumero do seu telefone principal:";
      cin >>telefone[linha];
      cout<<"\nNumero de pessoas que moram em sua casa incluindo voce:";
      cin >>npessoas[linha];
      cout<<"\nCadastrar outra pessoa?\n1=Cadastrar\n2-Sair\nResposta:";
      cin>>op;
      linha++;
     }while (op==1);
  }
};

int main(){
  Registrar_moradores p;
  p.cadastro();
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, acesse a [help] para obter ajuda sobre as ferramentas do site e para fazer bom proveito do mesmo.

Comment: Vê aí, que deve ter ocorrido um erro antes desse. Ele aparece porque seu `main` não retorna 0. Talvez porque, das duas, uma: um erro aconteceu, ou porque você não pôs `return 0.` no final do `main`